# How /can one fit a LMM with non-factor grouping variables in lme4?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I understood that lme4 can be used to fit LMMs including:
$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}} \,|\, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} = \boldsymbol b \;
 &\sim \;
\mathop{\mathcal N_n}
\left(
 \boldsymbol Z \boldsymbol b , 
\sigma^2 \boldsymbol I_n
\right), \\
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}
\;&\sim\;
\mathop{\mathcal N_q}
\left(
\mathbf 0,
\boldsymbol \Sigma_{\boldsymbol \theta}
\right), \\
\boldsymbol \Sigma_{\boldsymbol \theta}&= \sigma^2_\theta \boldsymbol I_q
\end{align}
$$
(here, $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}$ is a [$n$-variate random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable), the dependent variable, e.g. all observed evaluation-scores in bellow example, conditionally on the random effect  $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}$ taking the $q$-variate value $\boldsymbol{b}$ distributed as an ([isotropic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137851/90168)) [`n`-variate Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) with mean $\boldsymbol{Zb}$, the matrix-product of the $n\times q$ covariate matrix $\boldsymbol{Z}$ (i.e. the department the evaluated docent is from in below example) with $\boldsymbol{b}$ and [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) $\sigma^2 \boldsymbol I_n$ where $I_n$ is the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix), $\theta$ is only used as name, thus the [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) of $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}$ is $ \mathop{\mathcal N_n}
\left(\boldsymbol{0}, \sigma^2_\theta\boldsymbol{Z}\boldsymbol{Z^T}+
\sigma^2 \boldsymbol I_n
\right)$ )

but I can't figure out how to achieve this when $\boldsymbol Z$ is not a one-hot encoding of a factor variable.

Is this possible to fit this kind of model with lme4? If so, how? If not, which tools allow fitting such a model?

To be more specific, consider this example:

```r
library(lme4); set.seed(1)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#Let's fit a simple LMM for the teaching evaluation score with a random intercepts for 
# Student, DEParTment and Docent in order to measure how much of the total variance
# they explain:
lme4::lmer(y~(1|dept) +(1|d)+(1|s), InstEval) # the docent factor levels are globally unique, so this is equivalent to lme4::lmer(y ~ (1|dept/d)+(1|s), InstEval)
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: y ~ (1 | dept) + (1 | d) + (1 | s)
#>    Data: InstEval
#> REML criterion at convergence: 237774.9
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
#>  s        (Intercept) 0.32646 
#>  d        (Intercept) 0.51727 
#>  dept     (Intercept) 0.08197 
#>  Residual             1.17774 
#> Number of obs: 73421, groups:  s, 2972; d, 1128; dept, 14
#> Fixed Effects:
#> (Intercept)  
#>       3.252

# However, in the real world some docents have more than one affiliation:
Z_dept <- Matrix::t(Matrix::fac2sparse(InstEval$dept))
d2dept <- with(InstEval, sparseMatrix(d, dept))
d2dept[sample(length(d2dept), nrow(d2dept)*0.1)]  <- TRUE
Z_dept <- d2dept[InstEval$d,]

# But using a (sparse) matrix as grouping variable does not work:
lme4::lmer(y~(1|Z_dept) +(1|d)+(1|s), InstEval)
#> Error in model.frame.default(data = InstEval, drop.unused.levels = TRUE, : invalid type (S4) for variable 'Z_dept'
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It would be very useful to answerers to add some commentary on what your notation means here. One can make a guess at some of it, but otherwise it isn't totally clear.

Comment: added some. upper case of $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}$ is only due to math-jax not supporting lower case `\mathcal{}`...